# JavaScript input contains item in array

Tags: javascript, html, input

I was wondering if anybody know how to use the code below to make it so that if the input contains an item of the javascript array it will redirect the page using window.location.href?
Here is the code I have currently:

```
      var x = ["1", "2", "3"];


                  function validateForm() {
                    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
                    if (x != "59864") {
                      alert("doesnt contain");
                      return false;
                    }


                    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["value"].value;
                    if (x == "59864") {
                      window.location.href = "index.php";

                      return false;
                    }


                  }
```

Comment: why two times `x`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can be done. I have added a keyup listener, but you may want to use a different event (change, keydown, paste, etc)

```js
document.getElementById("I").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  console.log("here: " +this.value);
  if (this.value == "12345") {
    console.log("go to url");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="I" />
```